# Can you create an index to determine if a text column is null in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing, isnull

I have a very large (> 100 million rows) table and a query that I need to write needs to check if a column of type `TEXT` is null. I don't care about the actual text, only if the column value is null or not.

I'm trying to write an index to make that query efficient, and I want the query to be satisfied by only looking at the index e.g. such that the [explain output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) of that query shows `Using index` instead of `Using index condition`.

To be concrete, the table I'm dealing with has a structure like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    overridden TEXT,
    rowState VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    active TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And the query I want is this:

```sql
SELECT 
    IF(overridden IS NULL, "overridden", rowState) AS state, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM foo 
WHERE active=1
GROUP BY state
```

The `overridden` column is a description of why the column is overridden but, as I mentioned above, I don't care about its content, I only want to use it as a boolean flag.

I've tried creating an index on `(active, rowState, overridden(1))` but the explain output still shows `Using index condition`.

Is there something better that I could do?

Comment: Have you considered writing a Trigger that updates your Flag Column based on the length of the Text Column on Insert/Update? Your query would be against your Flag Column. Remove the Index on the Text column, unless you have other reasons to search it.

Comment: I have. What works even better than a trigger is a generated column with the value `overridden is not null`. That generated column can be indexed and makes the query very fast. The problem is, for reasons outside of my control, triggers and generated columns are not approaches I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this would be a good application for a "prefix" index.  (Most attempts at using such are a fiasco.)

The optimal order, I think, would be:

```
INDEX(active,         -- handle the entire WHERE first
      overridden(1),  -- IS NULL possibly works well
      rowState)       -- to make index "covering"
```

`Using index condition` means that the selection of the row(s) is handled in the Engine, not the "Handler".

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` may provide more insight into what is going on.  So might the "Optimizer trace".

**Or...**

If the MySQL version is new enough, create a "generated column" that persists with the computed value of `overridden IS NULL`.